# Flashing overdrive light 2002 ford escape

Tags: transmission, obd-ii, o2-sensor, sensor, p0171

2002 ford escape xlt-flashing overdrive light comes on after short period of driving. Comes on when approaching 50 mph? Or so...how do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I would take a guess that it's the torque converter trying to lock up and failing. Can you provide more details: only cold/only when warm? Is the check engine light set?